# Google script to create table of contents of files

Tags: google-apps-script

Unsure if this can be done or even where to start but the problem I've got currently is that we create files in one folder called policies and then we create a view able shareable link. We then copy this link into a separate table of contents doc for a quick way to open these files. The links are categorised in the table of contents under 5 set headings.

I was thinking if in the policy header doc I put what category it came under could a script grab this, use the file name and automatically paste this in the table of contents doc which starts on page 3 of the doc. That way the list would automatically be kept up to do and broken file links would be a thing of the past!

Comment: Can you post what code you've tried so far?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo nothing so far as I cant code. I was wondering if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

> automatically paste this in the table of contents doc which starts on page 3 of the doc.

#### Answer:

*No, it's the Table of Contents part that makes this not possible.*

#### Further information:

Unfortunately, the `TableOfContents` class of Apps Script doesn't have methods that allow you to manually update or refresh it's content programmatically. There is a feature request that seems to be related to this on Google's Issue Tracker which you can see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761940). You can also see the ToC structure [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#TableOfContents).

The Apps Script methods for Table of Contents can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-of-contents), though for the update-case you are looking for, I do not know how helpful it may be.

Also, you can however get the file name of a document if it's bound to the Doc using the [`DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document.html). If using a table of contents isn't the most pressing part of this, a workaround could certainly be done by making a Document table instead.

#### References:

- [Get Document parts using ToC on Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761940)
- [Table of Contents structure in the Docs API Reference](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#TableOfContents)
- [TableOfContents class of Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-of-contents)
- [DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. A document table would be perfect and its good to know that it can be done. Now its just a case of finding someone to help put it together as this is beyond my coding ability!

Comment: @RB No worries! If it answers your question please mark it as accepted so others that have the same issue in future can find the help they need!

Comment: Will do, If anyone has the time to help me with this code wise i'd appreciate it!